# Why won't .text().replace() work on td element? (jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, html-table

I can't get .replace to work on td elements. I've tried lost of variable methods I'm finding but nothing is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/h3mnj/

The html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="inv-amt">$567.98</td>
    <td class="inv-amt">$345.23</td>
    <td class="inv-amt">$211.09</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The js:

```
$(".inv-amt").each(function(){
    $(this).text().replace("$", "");
});
```

The end goal is I want to get the integer from the td so I can do something like:

```
$(".inv-amt").each(function(){
  if($(this).text() > 0){
    //Do something
  } else if($(this).text() < 0){
    //Do something else
  }
});
```

So I need to strip the $ out of the td so that it won't result in NaN. I've tried to parseFloat but can't get it to work. So I actually don't need to replace but it's not working and so I've resorted to trying to replace first, then compare the text. What can I do to accomplish either?

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on `replace`: _"Returns a **new string** with some or all matches..."_

Comment: So I was getting hung up on the fact it wasn't changing on screen when I didn't really need it to change, and actually didn't want it to changed. Doing comparisons like <code>$(this).text().replace("$", "") < 0)</code> works just fine. I'm a dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually set the text after you've done the replacement:

```
var newText = $(this).text().replace("$", "");
$(this).text(newText);
```

Comment: All the answers work so it was pretty hard to select just one. I choose your because it's already what I was doing, just never setting the text. Although, like most things, the code drastically changed since I wrote this since I realized I didn't actually need to strip them out at all, just do the replace ont he comparison and it works without having to actually set the text back.

Answer (score 5):

Try this way:

Issue is that you are not actually replacing the text that is in DOM. Instead you are replacing just the text value. You can utilize the `.text()` function to reset the value based on your condition.

```
$(".inv-amt").each(function(){
    $(this).text(function (_, oldValue){
        return oldValue.replace("$", "");
    })
});
```

You can just use `.text()` directly to replace it. NO need to iterate through.

```
$(".inv-amt").text(function (_, oldValue){
        return oldValue.replace("$", "");
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vFdad/)

Comment: @Douglas Yup this is useful in these kind of scenarios. Most of the methods say. html(), .text() etc has the function as argument that you can use.

Comment: Or if you're on jQuery 2.0+ (no IE8) then just go with `this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('$','')`

Comment: @elclanrs `textContent` is native js DOM element propery but it has support issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Comment: Yeah, IE9+ and all other "modern" browsers.

Comment: In old and new browsers, you could do `this.firstChild.replaceData(0,1,"");` though I don't think OP actually wants to update the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace("$", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/h3mnj/1/

The replace function returns text and doesn't actually edit the text.

Try this code:

```
$(".inv-amt").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace("$", "")); 
});
```